# basic diferences between root and real_root boot arg

Tags: kernel, grub2, boot-loader

I notice that we have set root=, but deeper there are real_root too.
Also why the real_root is rarely used?
I mean why it more common to use root rather the real_root?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the initial ram disk (**initrd**) or the initial ram fs (**initramfs**), then the bootloader will load both kernel and the initial ram disk/fs, then the kernel will manage the initial ram disk/fs to mount a temporary root fs into the memory.

Once the necessary drivers and modules are available then the initial ram disk/fs will need **real_root** parameter (passed by the grub to the kernel) to load the **real root fs partition** from a **block device** or over the network (via **nfsroot** grub parameter) then switch to it.

So in case your are not using the initial ram disk/fs, than means that all the necessary drivers and modules are **compiled within the kernel** then **real_root** will have no impact since no initial ram disk/fs is needed to finalize the boot sequence.